# Can you juggle the ball then punt it at a goalkick

Tags: rules, football

During a goalkick, are you allowed to have the ball start in the goalbox, but then you juggle the ball up into the air and punt it like that? Is that legal?

Answer (score 2):

No. [Law 16.2](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-goal-kick/#procedure) is as clear as it can be on this:

> If, after the ball is in play, the kicker touches the ball again before it has touched another player, an indirect free kick is awarded

Comment: And is there not still a rule which says a goal kick has to travel beyond the 18 yd box?  In the days when goalkeepers were allowed to handle a return pass, a frequent technique was for a goalkick to be played to a defender just outside the penalty area who would return it allowing the koalkeeper to pick up the ball and punt it further upfield.

Comment: @WS2 "When was this removed from the Laws of the Game" sounds like a fine separate question to ask if you're interested :)

Comment: The back-pass rule was introduced in 1992. This [Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-pass_rule) tells you all about it. It made playing the ball out of defence much more difficult

Comment: @WS2 That was meant to be a subtle hint not to ask new questions in comments :)

Comment: If I asked that question the first comment would be "How much research have you done and what does it tell you?" :)